# Linq query with MongoDB works does not work as Func

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I built a Linq query on a MongoDB collection, which retrieves properly my docs:

```
var parts = mongoParts.AsQueryable()
                       .Where(mongo => mongo.Prop1 == bmbMatch.Prop1 && mongo.Prop2 == bmbMatch.Prop2)
                       .ToList();
```

This works fine, but to make this less code I wrote a Generic function taking a

```
Func<T, T, bool> selector
```

Which take the exact same lamdba expression as in Where clause above, which makes it:

```
var mongo = mongoQuery.AsQueryable()
                      .Where(tmongo => selector(tmongo, localMatch))
                      .ToList();
```

with selector as :

```
(mongo, local) => mongo.Prop1== local.Prop1 && mongo.Prop2 == local.Prop2
```

This gives me a **"Unsupported where clause: "**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the internet

> Not all LINQ queries can be turned into equivalent MongoDB queries,
>   because C# allows you to write expressions that don't have any
>   equivalent in the MongoDB query language.

That being said, LINQ to MongoDB probably can't translate delegates.

You can find all supported LINQ queries on [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/) address.

Conclusion: If you need to query very large data or make queries as fast as possible, you will have to stick with the former solution. Otherwise, pull all data from your db and query them in-memory.

Comment: That's really a pity, as this would dimplify in certain scenario a lot of work :)

Comment: Well, maybe in the future :)